# Any Good tutorial on FakeItEasy

Tags: mocking, fakeiteasy

We are considering using FakeItEasy to be our mocking framework.

To conduct a workshop for the team on FakeItEasy, I am looking for a good tutorial that explains this framework in much details. I tried looking at the documentation at github, but found it very succinct.

If you know a good elaborate page/video, could you please point me to it. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this free book by [syncfusion](https://www.syncfusion.com/resources/techportal/details/ebooks/fakeiteasy)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you looked at [Patrik Hägne's sample/tutorial](http://ondevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/05/fakeiteasy-login-service-example-series.html?m=1)? It's a little old, but may help.

As you noticed, the documentation could use some fleshing out.
[We're working on it.](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/issues/143)

An alternative would be the [PluralSight FakeItEasy course](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/fakeiteasy). I've watched it and thought it to be quite good. I think it's short enough to watch as part of their free trial.

Me, I was familiar with mocking concepts and just tried it out. The fluent syntax guided me along well enough. Try it - you may be pleasantly surprised.

Answer (score 7):

I suggest you find a "general purpose" tutorial on Mocking and update it with FakeItEasy API.
A while back I wrote simple tutorial using Moq & Isolator which is a good place to start:

- [Getting started with Fake Objects – Part 1: why fake is better then
  mock](http://blog.drorhelper.com/2010/02/getting-started-with-fake-objects-part.html)
- [Getting started with Fake Objects – Part 2: How to create
  a fake object](http://blog.drorhelper.com/2010/02/getting-started-with-fake-objects-part_24.html)
- [Getting started with Fake Objects – Part 3: Verify that a call has been made](http://blog.drorhelper.com/2010/03/getting-started-with-fake-objects-part.html)

This is the basic Mocking functionality that all Mocking frameworks share. 
There are other similar tutorials on the web - just Google it.

Remember that most of FakeItEasy functionality is available from the same entry point - "A.", just explore the API and the minimal documentation to find how are things done.

Comment: The code text in those posts is cut off on the right edge.

Comment: I'll fix those - thanks for letting me know